# Why am I forced to use the newest chat interface?

Tags: discussion, chat, mobile-web

When logging into chat-stackexange I am presented with this message:

> The new mobile version of chat is now the default mobile version on devices that support it.
>
> Unlike the classic (okay, ancient) version, it allows you to perform actions like editing, starring, and direct replies to particular messages.
>
> The classic version is still available and will be used in browsers that lack support for some necessary features of the new version. Logged in users can also **choose to continue using the old version on the preferences page of their user profile.**
>
> Please report bugs and other issues on Meta Stack Exchange. Thank you!

I choose to continue using the old version but cannot find the option to do so on my chat user profile page?

Comment: I use chrome  - go to the 3 dots in top right, and select "use desktop version" near the bottom of the list, just above settings.

Comment: What phone OS are you using? I just upgraded to a phone running iOS 13 and I couldn’t get the desktop version of chat, no matter how often I requested it. Did some searching and it seems to be the OS forcing mobile versions even if you requested desktop version specifically. Might be a similar issue?

Comment: I think you're right @Catija iOS 8 doesn't force the mobile version when using the chrome browser, but when I change tabs it automatically forces the mobile version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find [your chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/6275/skullpatrol). Click on the prefs tab (look on the top right of the page)

[image: Prefs tab]

You should see this...

[image: Chat UI pref]

If you uncheck the pref you will likely need to refresh the page to get the new interface. You may also need to wait a few minutes in case there's any caching going on.

Comment: The box is not checked, sir.

Comment: Then report that as a separate bug/question (since this one is about finding the pref). Unless you've only just unchecked it, in which case refresh the page and/or wait a few minutes in case of caching.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for your attention.