# I can't turn off the new mobile chat interface even though the option is not activated in Preferences

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

Referring to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341392/why-am-i-forced-to-use-the-newest-chat-interface) about being forced to use the new mobile interface.

In the Answer, we are told to go to our chat preferences and make sure that checkbox is not activated. The OP says it was not activated on their machine and I see the same.

I tried activating, then de-activating with the following results:

1. Activating changed the mobile view to the **new** mobile view. In that view, clicking "Full Screen" had no effect.
2. De-activating changed back to the old mobile view, and still "Full Screen" did not change the view.

Whatever was changed over the last couple of days has completely turned off the Full Screen option for mobile devices. (In my case, I'm using an iPad.)

This is annoying as I'm a Room Owner and use the information presented in the sidebar on the right.

I ran into this [problem back in October](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335390/use-the-non-mobile-chat-interface-on-ipad), when something was changed, and at that time "Full Screen" was still effective.

How can we get that turned back on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, yeah that was broken.

It turns out that the cookie we used to track whether you wanted to use the mobile UI expired on [Jan 1st, 2020](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1214967050889826304)...so that's why it stopped working:

> [image]

This was just fixed to extend the expiration until Jan 1st, 2030, so on Jan 2nd, 2030 it will stop working again.

Comment: YES - thank you for extending the cookie. Not sure, though, why this would interfere with choosing the "Full site" item from the menu... But I'm happy, now :-)

Comment: If I'll eat the cookie, it will help? ;)